# Packet sniffing with channel hopping using scapy

Tags: wifi, monitoring

I have set up scapy on linux (raspian on RPI) for sniffing WiFi packets using WiFi adapter (b/g) in monitor mode. I am not sure if scapy by default hops on all the channels of the b/g protocol, or sticks to just one of them.

I'd like to have the capability to sniff different channels by hopping on to them, and to have capability to configure the dwell time on each channel, all using snapy. Can some one help me how to do that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use a bash script with `iwconfig` to do this. Have a look at this [project](https://github.com/jldupont/jldcmds).

Comment: Please add some tips onto how.

Comment: Edited with a link to a project of mine that could be useful.

Comment: In keeping with [our policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps :

1. Write a script in python (scapy) to sniff your desired traffic.
2. Write a script in bash with `iwconfig` (as [mentioned above](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/28668/5538)) with following   syntax:

   ```
   for i in {1..13}
   do
       iwconfig $1 channel $i
       sleep 5s
   done
   ```

   Or use `while` if you want.
3. Finally use the `&` operator to run both of them.

NOTE: keep both scripts in same directory or you have to use environment variables.

finally for your answer both scripts running:

[SCAPY/BASH (CHANNEL HOPPING) WORKING CODE](https://gist.github.com/Maitm29/5bf179b2f42d1b3f0a965214e8ce6cdf#file-mysniffer-sh)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/51708)

Comment: Sorry  Review will keep that in mind next time. Although that's my Github link so it will be up...

Comment: In keeping with [our policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.